# Pyinstaller Is it possible to generate binary file to run on CentOs under Windows?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am developing Python script with Selenium under Windows10.

To automation test the web, is it possible to generate a binary file to run on CentOs under Windows10 by Pyinstaller?

Or I **MUST** be under the same OS which I would like to run?

And I want to check, is it correct that a file generated by Pyinstaller(or any other tool?) could run on the environment without any python-installation?

Comment: A binary/executible is _designed_ to run without having to install Python, or any other languages.

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino Copied that, how about another problem?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that pyinstaller makes a binary in Linux:

"PyInstaller freezes (packages) Python applications into stand-alone executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX."

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

However, when you try to make a package that works on CentOS, you had better make it on that CentOS.